# C# GMapControl GetPoint error

Tags: c#, google-maps

I'm using the GMap control in C#, in a Windows Form application.

I made an app that puts in a map some coordinates. When I use it, from my pc, it works perfectly.

When I try to run the app on other PCs, the coordinates are not given.
Check the comments below in my code.

```
GeoCoderStatusCode status;
//Here I search the address and the city
PointLatLng? punt = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetPoint(punti[i].Address+ ", " + punti[i].City, out status);
//At this I point I check if I received the data
if (status == GeoCoderStatusCode.G_GEO_SUCCESS)
{
    double la = punt.Value.Lat;
    double lo = punt.Value.Lng;
    marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(la, lo), GMarkerGoogleType.green_dot);
    punti[i].Latitudine = la;
    punti[i].Longitudine = lo;
}
//If the data is not received...
else
{
    //I use some default data (that I get from a txt) based on the city
    marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(lat, lng), GMarkerGoogleType.green_dot);
}
marker.ToolTipText = punti[i].Name+ "\r\n\r\n" + punti[i].Address+ " - " + punti[i].City;
marker.ToolTip = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.ToolTips.GMapRoundedToolTip(marker);
```

You understand that if the data are not received I will build a map with lots of markers in the same point.

I repeat: if I use the app from my PC, the markers are put in the right position on the map. The problem occurs only when the app runs on other PCs.

I tried also changing the GMapProvider, but the problem is still there.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Emmanuele

Comment: "Google Maps API for Work client IDs are restricted to URLs specifically authorized. If you try to use your client ID at a URL that has not been authorized, you will receive an error message." [Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/troubleshooting_auth). Your app is authorized from your PC's IP only.

Comment: Thank you very much Mogsdad. What if I build a web app? The win forms app I built in these days was a test for a future web app. So, will this fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go about it. So all your api requests originate from one authorized server.

Comment: Great, you helped me a lot. Thank you very much for your help and availability. If you want, answer to my question with your comments, then I will give you the vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Google Maps API for Work client IDs are restricted to URLs specifically authorized. If you try to use your client ID at a URL that has not been authorized, you will receive an error message.
>   <sup>[Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/troubleshooting_auth)</sup>

Your app is authorized from your PC's IP only, so using your key to make requests from other machines results in the error you've received.

Instead of invoking the api from clients, you are expected to restrict it to a single authorized server, and then extend your own web service to clients.